# Employee and check the prime age for each employee

Tags: java, project

I have problem in using the value from Employee age and I have primeagechecker. 
Employee has the value for age itself. Primeagechecker is only checking if it's prime or not.Then just println some command "The age is prime." if it's prime.I'm not a java person, I'm beginner in Java.Result is always false for the age check.
Thanks for helping.

Here is my code.

```
public class Employee {
    String name;
    boolean check;
    int age;
    Department department;
    public ArrayList<Employee> emplo;

    static Employee emp1 = new Employee(Department.Accounting,"Counting Guru",55);
    static Employee emp2 = new Employee(Department.Accounting,"Counting Pro", 45);
    static Employee emp3 = new Employee(Department.Accounting,"Counting Savvy", 40);
    static Employee emp4 = new Employee(Department.Accounting,"Counting Novice", 25);
    static Employee emp5 = new Employee(Department.Marketing,"Sales Guru", 50);
    static Employee emp6 = new Employee(Department.Marketing,"Sales Pro", 48);
    static Employee emp7 = new Employee(Department.Marketing,"Sales Savvy", 38);
    static Employee emp8 = new Employee(Department.Human_Resources,"Hiring Guru", 58);
    static Employee emp9 = new Employee(Department.Human_Resources,"Hiring Pro", 47);
    static Employee emp10 = new Employee(Department.Information_Systems,"Hacking Pro", 46);
    static Employee emp11 = new Employee(Department.Information_Systems,"Hacking Guru", 51);
    static Employee emp12 = new Employee(Department.Information_Systems,"Hacking Savvy", 38);
    static Employee emp13 = new Employee(Department.Information_Systems,"Hacking Novice", 23);

    Employee(Department department,String name, int age)
    {
        this.department = department;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean GetChecker()
    {
        return check;

    }

    public void addEmplo(Employee x){
        if (emplo.isEmpty())
        {
            emplo.add(x);
        }
        else
        {
            int i;
            for ( i = 0;i <emplo.size(); ++i){
                if(emplo.get(i).getAge() > x.getAge()){
                    emplo.add(i,x);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if ( i == emplo.size()){
                emplo.add(x);
            }
        }
        }

    public ArrayList<Employee> getEmplo(){
        return emplo;
    }

    public String toString(){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(getDept(department));
        sb.append("\t");
        sb.append(getName());
        sb.append("\t");
        sb.append(getAge());
        sb.append("\t");
        sb.append(GetChecker());

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private Department getDept(Department department){
        return department;
    }

}





public class PrimeAgeChecker{

    Employee age;

    PrimeAgeChecker(Employee age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public boolean check(){

        boolean status = false;

        for (int a = 2; a < age; ++a){
            if (age % a == 0)
            {
                status = true;
            }
        }

        return status;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your prime age checker your age is of type Employee, which is not some type of number. I'm not even sure that `a < age` should compile.

Whatever is happening you're trying to see if an Employee is divisible by an int, which isn't going to happen. Your age in PrimeAgeChecker should be defined as an int and be set using employee.getAge()

Comment: Hi Jomo,
Can you tell me how to get the age in Employee in the PrimeAgeCheck?
Thanks

Comment: employee.getAge() where employee is an object of type Employee.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have not omitted anything, you never evoke the method `check()`, `check` is not the same as `check()`. In fact, you don't have an instance of `PrimeAgeChecker`.

Either add a `static` modifier to `PrimeAgeChecker` and call `PrimeAgeChecker.check()`,
or do something like `PrimeAgeChecker pac=new PrimeAgeChecker();pac.check();`